# How to make imperative sentence in past perfect tense

Tags: past-perfect

For example  I ordered my student to complete their homework before their parents come to the home. In this case Would it be correct if I say sentence below by using past perfect tense?

> Had already completed your homework when your parents come to home.

I think it is not correct but I couldn’t find better way than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imperative in a past tense doesn't make sense.

It is probably grammatical, but very unusual, to use a present perfect imperative:

> Have completed your homework when your parents come home.

More common would be

> Have your homework completed when your parents come home

(this is not a perfect: it is substanive "have", with adjectival "completed".

but much more common than that would be either

> Do you homework before your parents come home

or

> Get your homework done before your parents come home.

Comment: Thank you so much.